# User Input Database in VB

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to accept different Databases into VB for both a DataGridView and To use part of in order to send emails out to the people in the database? 
I have already created a program that Allows you to send SMS messages from a VB form and sending either to 1 person or to an entire database.
So is there a way to let the user decide the database?

Answer (score 0):

A data base is just a store of information. You use as many stores as you need. How you use them is down to the abstractions and structure you use in your code. For example you could use ADO.NET and then switch the connection string to other databases.

Comment: Alright thanks for the other point of view ill try to implement something